# Wufoo - POSTing to Form API - form can't accept new entries

Tags: php, forms, wufoo

I am using the Wufoo form api to POST to a form on my account, But despite following the documentation I run into this error:

> This form can't accept new entries. Please inform the owner of the form so they can contact Wufoo Support

So far the following requirements have been met:

- Using correct subdomain and form identifier
- Using version 3
- Response = JSON
- Using Basic Authentication used with API Key and password
- Sending the parameters as an array **"FieldID" => "Value"**
- Form set to public
- Password protected my form

Yet I still get this error, is there anything else I / the documentation is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was very frustrated by this issue too.. it seems that that response is given **anytime you give the API form ID's it's not expecting** (like Field4, Field4-1, Field4-2) instead of simply combining them into one Field (at least for me)

I had a phone number field that wuFoo split into 3 parameters:

```
<li id="foli4" class="phone notranslate">
    <label class="desc" id="title4" for="Field4">
        Phone Number
    </label>
    <span>
        <input id="Field4" name="Field4" type="tel" class="field text" value="" size="3" maxlength="3" tabindex="4"/>
        <label for="Field4">###</label>
    </span>
    <span class="symbol">-</span>
    <span>
        <input id="Field4-1" name="Field4-1" type="tel" class="field text" value="" size="3" maxlength="3" tabindex="5" />
        <label for="Field4-1">###</label>
    </span>
    <span class="symbol">-</span>
    <span>
        <input id="Field4-2" name="Field4-2" type="tel" class="field text" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" tabindex="6" />
        <label for="Field4-2">####</label>
    </span>
</li>
```

In PHP, I decomposed this via http_build_query($_POST) into:
`Field4=555&Field4-1=555&Field4-2=5555` and sent it via the boilerplate code they provide over cURL https://wufoo.github.io/docs/?shell#submit-entry.

Sending this returned the response:

```
{"Success":0,"ErrorText":"This form can't accept new entries. Please inform the owner of the form so they can contact Wufoo Support.","FieldErrors":[]}
```

When I sent this However:

`Field4=5555555555` in my post body, the form submission succeeds!

**It appears that even though WuFoo splits parts of its form into several components, it's expecting the response to be concatenated together, otherwise it freaks out.**

Hope this helps all of you out there struggling with the WuFoo API!